# Tkinter resizing grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid

I have my labels arranged in a grid with label3 sticky to SE side of its cell.

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.label1 = Label(parent, text = "Column 1")
        self.label2 = Label(parent, text = "Column 2")
        self.label3 = Label(parent, text = "Column 3")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.label3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=SE)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
sale = GUI(root)
root.title("Example")
root.mainloop()
```

When I run the program the grid takes up a small portion of the total size of the window. How do I get label3 to stick to the bottom right corner of the window in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

The [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) alignment method determines the size of each row and column in the grid using the size of the largest widgets in them.

So, if you want the "Column 3" text to appear at the bottom right corner of the GUI, you can make your third label bigger by manually setting its `width` and `height`:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.label1 = Label(parent, text="Column 1", bg='red')
        self.label2 = Label(parent, text="Column 2", bg='blue')
        self.label3 = Label(parent, text="Column 3", bg='green', 
                            width=97, height=39, anchor=SE)
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
        self.label3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=SE)

root = Tk()
#root.geometry("800x600")
sale = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Another option is to use the [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) alignment method:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.label1 = Label(parent, text="Column 1", bg='red', anchor=N)
        self.label2 = Label(parent, text="Column 2", bg='blue', anchor=N)
        self.label3 = Label(parent, text="Column 3", bg='green', anchor=SE)
        self.label1.pack(fill=Y, side='left')
        self.label2.pack(fill=Y, side='left')
        self.label3.pack(fill=X, side='bottom')

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
sale = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```